# Why does the { position affects this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I spent a fair bit of time on this Javascript issue (you can tell I am a JS noob):

Take some well written Javascript code [like this example](http://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) of the Revealing Module Pattern:

Running it works fine. Then move the "{" to the next line (as a C# developer I set up all my environments to put curly braces on new lines) and run it again.

```
  return   
  {
    someMethod : myMethod,
    someOtherMethod : myOtherMethod
  };
```

It now gets quite a few JS errors around "13    Line breaking error 'return'." and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " in Chrome Debugger.

My question is, how can something syntactically affect the Javascript like this?

I have [set it up here in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyjoyce/Vr77L/1/)  (to get it to work, move the { after "return" back on to the same line)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of JavaScript’s worst features is Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

```
return; // a semicolon is implicitly inserted here
```

And this part is almost valid JavaScript, but not quite, so you get a syntax error:

```
{
    someMethod : myMethod,
    someOtherMethod : myOtherMethod
};
```

If you had tried to do this:

```
return
    [ 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9 ];
```

it would have just returned `undefined` all the time, and that would have been bad. ASI sucks, but we’re stuck with it now, especially since semicolonless code has become a fad.

What does this do?

```
return a
     + b
     + c;
```

This?

```
return e
     / f /g;
```

Okay, okay, maybe that one’s a bit contrived, and maybe this isn’t entirely topical. But ASI is bad. I hope everyone gets that.

Answer (score 9):

Because the [ECMA standard section 12.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) states you can't have a new line between the `return` keyword and its expression.

```
    ReturnStatement :
       return ;
       return [no LineTerminator here] Expression ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does something called [Automatic semi-colon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) which I believe is what is affecting your results here.  Basically, it sees the `return` statement with nothing after on the line, and thinks that's the end of the line and returns, ending the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because **return** expects a value (or variable), when you put the curly brace in the same line you are telling **return a hash** but if you move the curly brace to the next line then you are telling **return nothing** so the next line is not expected.

**EDIT**
The next line is not expected in the context of return.

Comment: Everything is correct except of this: "so the next line is not expected". Next line is expected, but the `{ foo: 'bar' };` statement is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Edited to do a more explained answer for "so the next line is not expected"

Comment: Okay. "Because return expects a value (or variable)" --- `console.log()` also expects an expression but you can split it into multiple lines. "expecting a value" doesn't mean it cannot be put into another line.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has some strange bits to it and one is that the position of the brackets matters - keep the opening one on the same line as the code

http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/

Comment: "is that the position of the brackets matters" --- it's not. A position of expression matters, not curly braces specifically.

Comment: That blog posts sums it up well, thank you- I might have to re-consider my formatting