# React Promise: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I need to post something on my API. 
I have this function which works correctly:

TradeContainer.js:

```
callApi(action){
  var actionInfo = {
      user_id: this.props.currentUser.id,
      action: action
  }

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/actions', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(actionInfo)
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
 }
```

I want to move fetch() to another file from where i make all API calls. In that file I already have several fetch functions (with get method) and they work fine. 
But when I move this fetch() with post method to that file, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

My code:

TradeContainer.js:

```
import { saveAction } from '../components/apiCalls.js'

callApi(action){
  var actionInfo = {
      user_id: this.props.currentUser.id,
      action: action
  }

   //this is fetch() function that i moved to apiCalls.js file. 
   //And this two lines of code throw an error.
  saveAction(actionInfo)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
 }
```

apiCalls.js

```
export function saveAction(actionInfo){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/actions', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(actionInfo)
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
}
```

.then(res => res.json()) returns "ok" and 200. 
but **saveAction(actionInfo)** returns **undefined**. How come?

Comment: `saveAction` does not return anything.

Comment: You need to return the promise that comes back from the call

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `saveAction` doesn't return anything (specifically - doesn't return promise) so you can't use `then` on that function:

```
export function saveAction(actionInfo){
  fetch({
     ...
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
}
```

You can return the `fetch` (which is a promise) and then you can use `then` on that function:

```
export function saveAction(actionInfo){
  return fetch({
     ...
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
}
```

Comment: I thought that it was something that simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If it may be of any help for noobs like me,make sure the `return` and the `fetch` statement are on the same line, or surround the `fetch` statement in parenthesis.
Avoid this! it will also cause the `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.

```
function fetchData(){
    return 
       fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
    }
```

Try this.

```
function fetchData(){
    return (
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json()))
    }
```

Comment: related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185128/why-does-the-position-affects-this-javascript-code fetch isn't the only thing that putting a newline between return and its value can break.